Replace an element of a list with its value from a dataframe
I have a data dictionary and a column_list. I want to replace the value in the column_list with its matching value from the data dictionary. I have written the below code; however, I'm unable to get the required output.
Can someone please help to fix the overlapping values?
col_list = ['eff_strt_dte', 'eff_sta_dt', 'birth_dt', 'cus_idr', 'cust_id']
data_dict = {'eff': 'effective', 'dt': 'date', 'dte': 'date', 'str': 'start', 'cus': 'customer', 'cust': 'customer', 'id':'identifier', 'idr': 'identifier', 'sta': 'start'}

new_list = []
for col in col_list:
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if key in col:
            col = col.replace(key, value)
    new_list.append(col)
print(new_list)

Expected output is:
['effective_start_date', 'effective_start_date', 'birth_date', 'customer_identifier', 'customer_identifier']
Output I'm getting now: ['effective_startt_datee', 'effective_sta_date', 'birth_date', 'customeromer_identifierr', 'customeromert_identifier']

You're almost there! Simply replace
        if key in col:

with
        if key in col.split('_'):

and include the key-value pair 'strt': 'start' in data_dict
Depending on the size of data_dict, it might be inefficient to loop over the entire dict every time. An alternative approach would be to loop over col.split('_') first and using dict.get to replace an abbreviation:
new_list = []
for col in col_list:
    new_list.append(
        '_'.join(
            data_dict.get(abbr, abbr)  # use original value if it isn't a known abbreviation
            for abbr in col.split('_')
        )
    )

Explanation:

iterate over col_list just like before
split col at '_', e.g. 'eff_strt_dte' will be split to ['eff', 'strt', 'dte']
assume these parts are abbreviations that can be expanded with the help of data_dict by simply looking them up
if the lookup fails, it should return the original value. For example, 'birth_dt' will be split to ['birth', 'dt'], but 'birth' is not a key of data_dict. data_dict[abbr] would raise a KeyError when abbr is 'birth', so something like data_dict.get(abbr) would be more appropriate. This returns None if the key is not found, instead of raising an exception. We can also specify a different default return value for that case, so we don't have to check for None manually. The custom default is the second argument of data_dict.get(abbr, abbr)
'_'.join(...) creates a string out of the new parts, separating them with an underscore. These are the strings we want to have in new_list


Thanks for optimising the code but I didn't get the abbr part here and how is it working?

@be_real I added an explanation for it, I hope it helps

You could also take a regex approach to this, making a regex from the keys of data_dict and using the matched string to look up its replacement:
col_list = ['eff_strt_dte', 'eff_sta_dt', 'birth_dt', 'cus_idr', 'cust_id']
data_dict = {
    'eff': 'effective',
    'dt': 'date',
    'dte': 'date',
    'str': 'start',
    'cus': 'customer',
    'cust': 'customer',
    'id':'identifier',
    'idr': 'identifier',
    'sta': 'start',
    'strt' : 'start'
}

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(sorted(data_dict.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)))
out = [pattern.sub(lambda m:data_dict[m.group()], col) for col in col_list]

Output:
['effective_start_date', 'effective_start_date', 'birth_date', 'customer_identifier', 'customer_identifier']

Notes:

for this to work properly you need to sort the match strings in order of descending length (so for example you don't match id in idr)
in this code I've added 'strt': 'start' to data_dict.

